# Please help me understand Arrays

Tags: java

I am in my 4th week of programming and my teacher is moving VERY quickly. I am so confused. I very vaguely understand arrays as is. My teacher wants us to create an array (a double) that has 50 elements, I need to loop through that array and have the first 25 have an if statement set to the index squared, the else 3x the index. I need to print that out 10 per line. This is so way over my head and of course my teacher is not going to be available Saturday or Sunday (it is due Sunday). After I got clarification on what the teacher wanted it was Wednesday. I have been going crazy trying to figure out how to do this. I am not asking for an answer, just good solid direction.

Correspondence email from teacher while I was asking for clarification."You’re on the right track but not quite there. The index variable isn’t a set number; it is a reference to a value in the array.  So in the statement:
array[count] = 5; 
count is the index variable and that is the value we are basing our calculations on.  Since it changes, our output would be more like:

- 0 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81
- 100 121 .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..
- .. .. .. .. .. 75 78 81 84 87
- .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..
- .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..

Notice also that they should be a full 10 to a line making line 3 have 5 from each of the calculations together."

Comment: There are plenty tutorials on the net about arrays, including [The Official Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html). Please provide your code and what issues you have with it.

Comment: The line "I need to loop through that array and have the first 25 have an if statement set to the index squared, the else 3x the index" is particularly confusing. An if statement needs a `boolean` (`true` or `false`) condition. If the condition is true, it will do something. In order for you to have an if statement, you need a condition. What is this condition? Also, when asking questions on Stack Overflow, please provide some information on what you have tried, and not only what is not working. That way, if there is something wrong with your code, we can try an fix your code and make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**first part**

```
double[] arr=new double[50];
for(int i=0;i<25;i++)
    arr[i]=i*i;
```

**second part**

```
for(int i=25;i<arr.length;i++)
   arr[i]=3*i;
```

**third part**

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{

         if((i%10==0)&&i!=0)
             System.out.println(arr[i]+" ");
           else
             System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");


}
```

I'm not sure if i understood you but the first part is the squared index, the second is the double index, the third is printing the array, notice that after every 10 printings it goes to a new line.

Comment: Thank you very much. I actually understand what is going on here but I am not sure if I could have coded that. I have to be making this harder than what it is somehow.

Comment: Which part do you think you couldn't have written?

Comment: Well, I got your first 5 lines in a file already done, after that my mind was just going blank. I wish she wasn't moving so freaking fast with us. If I had not have fiddled around with python already I don't even think that I would have gotten this far to be honest.